# When I make the statement root->right->right = newnode(7); a comment, the compiler shows a runtime error.Can anyone explain why?

Tags: c++, gcc, runtime-error

I'm writing the code for calculating the total number of root to leaf paths in a binary tree in C++.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<queue>
using namespace std;  
struct node  
{int data;  
 struct node *left;  
 struct node *right;  
};

struct node* newnode(int data)  
{struct node* node = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));  
 node->data = data;  
 node->left = NULL;  
 node->right = NULL;  
 return node;  
}

int root_to_leaf_paths(struct node *root)  
{if(root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL)  
  return 1;  
 else if(root == NULL)  
   return 0;  
 else  
   return(root_to_leaf_paths(root->left)+root_to_leaf_paths(root->right));  

}

int main()  
{
 struct node *root = newnode(1);  
 root->left = newnode(2);  
 root->right = newnode(3);  
 root->left->left = newnode(4);  
 root->left->right = newnode(5);  
 root->right->left = newnode(6);
```

When I add make the below line comment, compiler shows runtime error.

```
 **//root->right->right = newnode(7);**  

printf("%d",root_to_leaf_paths(root));  
}
```

Comment: What compiler are you using? And does it give an error message?

Comment: @chtz I am using gcc +5.1 compiler.It shows the error message "runtime error".

Comment: @pang This is C++.

Comment: @VedantDixit: No the compiler doesn't show you a "runtime error" message. You can get such a message when you run your program. But not when you compile it. Please try to be more precise. Provide a console text dump, or perhaps a screen shot. Text is best. Screen shot better than nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of conditions is backwards:

```
 if(root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL)  
  return 1;  
 else if(root == NULL)  
   return 0;  
 else  
   return(root_to_leaf_paths(root->left)+root_to_leaf_paths(root->right));
```

You need to first ascertain that `root` isn't null before you can access `root->left` etc.